# Flipping image causes massive RAM/CPU uses with AForge.net

Tags: aforge

Hey all i am trying to figure out why when i flip the image it uses a LOT of RAM and CPU (its an quad core i7)

I use this code:

```
Dim filter As New RotateBilinear(180, True)
image = Filter.Apply(image)

  If bIsToRecord Then
        If writer Is Nothing Then
            Dim [date] As DateTime = DateTime.Now
            Dim fileName As [String] = [String].Format("{0},{1}.avi",[date].Minute, [date].Second)

            Try
                OpenWriter(fileName, image.Width, image.Height)
            Catch ex As Exception
                If writer IsNot Nothing Then
                    writer.Dispose()
                    writer = Nothing
                End If
            End Try
        End If

        Try
            If radioButton1.Checked Then
                writer.AddFrame(image)
            Else
                mVideoFileWriter.WriteVideoFrame(image)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End If
```

[image]
That is WITHOUT flipping the images

[image]
WITH the flipping...

Each screenshot was for 30 seconds.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant but you're not flipping, you are rotating 180°. Incidentally, try with the Mirror filter, passing true for both X-axis and Y-axis would also do a 180° rotation, maybe more lightweight.

Comment: Also, considering the rotation you're doing, you don't need it to be Bilinear. NearestNeighbor would suffice.